# suppress stdout warning messages in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

how can i suppress warning message on ubuntu terminal, I am currently getting:

`Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. message.`

I tried using:

`2>/dev/null | grep -v "Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure"`

but it suppresses all kinds of errors. Please help.

Comment: You are sending all errors to /dev/null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two things: `2>/dev/null` routes the standard *error* to /dev/null, and `grep -v "Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure"` filters out any occurence of the string from the standard *output*.

Your warning message goes to the standard error, so it is being affected by the redirect (`>`). The grep part is effectively being useless since it only affects the standard output.

You could try merging the standard error to the standard output, then filtering out this warning:
`2>&1 | grep -v "Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure"`.

Please be aware that embedding passwords directly within commands is, indeed, insecure. One can recover it using your shell's history file. One day you might use a shared server, please remember this.